# how to add bar value on the top (catplot seaborn )?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

Data is in below form:

```
first_name nick_name              activity                         duration            
  Harish   Escorts   MC GUARD ASSEMBLY WITH CABINATE BRACKET          226   
  Harish   Escorts   COOLANT TANK AND SIDE DOORS, OPP DOORS           225   
Narasaraj  Escorts   MC GUARD ASSEMBLY WITH CABINATE AND BRACKET MO   225   
Narasaraj  Escorts   COOLANT TANK AND SIDE DOORS, OPP DOORS ASSEMBLY  150
PurushothamEscorts   PNEUMATIC AND LUBRICATION ASSEMBLY                55
Shivu      Escorts   CABLE CARRIER AND AXIS MOTOR ASSEMBLY            123
```

Using seaborn I am doing a barplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)


df = pd.read_excel('VMC & HMC data (sep&oct-15).xlsx',  index = False)

df1 = df1[[ "first_name" , "nick_name", "activity" , "duration"]]

g = sns.catplot(x= 'first_name', y = 'duration', hue = 'activity' , data = df1, kind = 'bar', dodge=False, palette="deep", ci = None)

plt.ylim(0,300)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    g.text(row.name,row.first_name,row.duration, color='black', ha="center")
```

It throws me error as :

```
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How to add values of bar on top of the bar??
[image: No values at the top of the bar]

Comment: @jezrael kindly have a look on my problem please :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried option A and got an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'text'.

Here's how I solved it:
You can add values for each bar by modifying the returned Facet grid.

```
g = sns.catplot(x='class', y='survival rate', 
            hue='sex', data=df, kind='bar')

ax = g.facet_axis(0,0)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_x() + 0.015, 
            p.get_height() * 1.02, 
            '{0:.2f}'.format(p.get_height()), 
            color='black', rotation='horizontal', size='large')
```

[image: catplot example]

Here's what the example data looks like, if you want to recreate my plot -

```
       class    sex   survival rate
   0    first   men    0.914680
   1    second  men    0.300120
   2    third   men    0.118990
   3    first   women  0.667971
   4    second  women   0.329380
   5    third   women   0.189747
   6    first   children    0.660562
   7    second  children    0.882608
   8    third   children    0.121259
```

Answer (score 1):

`catplot` returns a FacetGrid. This does not have a `text` method.

Two options:

#### A. Select an axes from the grid

- **if `catplot` produces multiple axes**

  ```
  g = sns.catplot(...)
  g.axes[0].text(...)
  ```
- **if `catplot`  produces a single axes**

  ```
  g = sns.catplot(...)
  g.axes.text(...)
  ```

#### B. Use a barplot

```
ax = sns.barplot(...)
ax.text(...)
```

Comment: Does `g.axes[0].text(...)` will be called under a `enumerate` loop ??

Comment: I tried `for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    g.axes[0].text(row.name,row.first_name, round(row.duration,2), color='black', ha="center")` but this give a error `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing`

Comment: I tried option A and got an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'text'. I have posted the solution that worked for me